# Overriding Springboot Beans in integration test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I know there are a lot of examples out there about overriding beans in integration tests, but I'm getting a bit confused with Springboot versions, and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I'm basically running a `@SpringBootTest` with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` and `RestAssured`. All annotations are in a base class I called `BaseIntegrationTest`, which looks like the following:

```kotlin
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(
    initializers = [BaseIntegrationTest.Companion.Initializer::class],
    classes = [BaseIntegrationTest.Companion.ClockConfiguration::class]
)
abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    var localPort: Int = 0

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEachTest() {
        RestAssured.port = localPort
    }

    companion object {

        @TestConfiguration
        class ClockConfiguration {

            @Bean
            fun mockClock(): Clock {
                return Clock.fixed(
                    LocalDate
                        .of(2022, 1, 1)
                        .atTime(0, 0)
                        .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC),
                    ZoneId.of("UTC")
                )
            }

            @Bean
            fun mockCountryService(): CountryService {
                return MockCountryService()
            }
        }

        class MockCountryService : CountryService() {
            override fun findByCode(countryCode: String): Country? {
                return null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a **nested** class with `@TestConfiguration` annotation (as I read it automatically recogizes it). By the way, I also included this `CountryService` bean because I was initially trying to mock the `Clock`, without success. I used this service to make sure that it was not a clock issue, but a bean overriding issue.

But when I run the tests, and put breakpoints along the production code, I see that what gets instantiated are the real beans, not these ones. I also tried to use `@Configuration` instead of `@TestConfiguration`, and adding `@Primary` to the beans here, but no luck.

If I remove the original beans, and I leave only these ones, then when debugging the production code I actually get the mocked beans, so I guess it has something to do in overriding them.

Springboot version is `2.7.2`

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!